# I want to display column name like "ID" "Name" ect while print table on richtextbox and also want table format

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

```
    This is my code to add data from datatable to richtextbox on table format
 dt = new DataTable();
                        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + folderPath + "\\" + databaseName);
                        InitializeComponent();
                        s = MyProperty.ToString();
                        conn.Open();
                        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT id,nameSearch,dt,totalRecords FROM ACCESSDETAILS Where id=" + s + " AND numberSearch IS NULL AND dt BETWEEN '" + datepicker + "' AND '" +  datepicker1+ "'", conn);
                        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
                        da.Fill(dt);                        
                        conn.Close() 
var tab = new Table();

                            var gridLenghtConvertor = new GridLengthConverter();
                            tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "ID", IsEnabled = true, Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("30") });
                            tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "Name", IsEnabled = true, Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("80") });
                            tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "Date", IsEnabled = true, Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("100") });
                            tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "TotalRecords", IsEnabled = true, Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("auto") });



                            tab.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
                            int i = 0;
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                tab.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
                                var tabRow = tab.RowGroups[0].Rows[i];
                                tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " | "))));
                                tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dr.ItemArray[1].ToString() + " | "))));
                                tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString() + " | "))));
                                tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dr.ItemArray[3].ToString()))));
                                i++;
                            }
                            rtf.Document.Blocks.Add(tab);
```

Here i am add column as well as columname but that name cannot display.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKStn.png)

This image is my print page on which i want id, name, date and total records as a column name. and i want border around it like below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvrYF.png)

Please help me .

Comment: Why do you want to use a rich text box, wouldn't a grid be more appropriate for displaying a table of data?

Comment: But in wpf how could I print data from grid because table contain multiple row and it may take more than two pages then how can i print it

Comment: If you want that level of control, I don't think a RTB is going to help much. How about using the iTextSharp library?

Comment: Can you give me an example, please

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/

Comment: so can i directly print datatable using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate columns when you create datatable. Refer below code as reference for your problem.

```
//Create datatable
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//put Your columns Name
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Total Records", typeof(string));

//Your Query Code
 SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + folderPath + "\\" + databaseName);
                        InitializeComponent();
                        s = MyProperty.ToString();
                        conn.Open();
                        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT id,nameSearch,dt,totalRecords FROM ACCESSDETAILS Where id=" + s + " AND numberSearch IS NULL AND dt BETWEEN '" + datepicker + "' AND '" +  datepicker1+ "'", conn);
                        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
                         ds = new DataSet();
                         da.Fill(ds);

#Fill Dataset values in Datatable rows   
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr[0] =Convert.ToInt32( ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"]);
                        dr[1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["namesearch"].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["lastname"].ToString(); 
                        dr[2] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dt"].ToString();
                        dr[3] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["totalRecords"].ToString();
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }                     
                        conn.Close() ;

#For Print Datatable

            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

                Table table = new Table();
                TableRowGroup tableRowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
                TableRow r = new TableRow();
                fd.PageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
                fd.PageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
                fd.BringIntoView();

                fd.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                fd.ColumnWidth = 500;
                table.CellSpacing = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    r.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph(new Run(dt.Columns[j].ToString()))));
                    r.Cells[j].ColumnSpan = 4;
                    r.Cells[j].Padding = new Thickness(4);
                    r.Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                    r.Cells[j].FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    r.Cells[j].Background = Brushes.DarkGray;
                    r.Cells[j].Foreground = Brushes.White;
                    r.Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
                }
                tableRowGroup.Rows.Add(r);
                table.RowGroups.Add(tableRowGroup);

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var gv = dt.Rows[i];
                    tableRowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
                    r = new TableRow();
                    for (int j = 0; j < gv.ItemArray.Length; j++)
                    {
                        r.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph(new Run(gv.ItemArray[j].ToString()))));
                        r.Cells[j].ColumnSpan = 4;
                        r.Cells[j].Padding = new Thickness(4);
                        r.Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                        r.Cells[j].Background = Brushes.White;
                        r.Cells[j].Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                        r.Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
                    }
                    tableRowGroup.Rows.Add(r);
                    table.RowGroups.Add(tableRowGroup);
                }

                fd.Blocks.Add(table);

                printDialog.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource) fd).DocumentPaginator, "");

            }
        }
```

Comment: var gv = columnfilter.Rows[i]; what is columnfilter here